# Sorting Array of Dates with String in mix

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a set of strings like this:

```
 "No Value"
 04/08/2014 
 04/16/2014
 04/18/2014
 04/21/2014
```

I wanted them sorted ascending like I have above and implemented code like:

```
 data.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.label === "No Value" || b.label === "No Value") return 1;
    return new Date(a.label) - new Date(b.label);
 });
```

however my sort always comes back like:

```
 04/08/2014 
 "No Value"
 04/16/2014
 04/18/2014
 04/21/2014
```

What am i doing wrong here?  Seems straight forward.

Comment: `if(a.label === "No Value" || b.label === "No Value") return 1;` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.label === "No Value")
        return -1;
    else if(b.label === "No Value") 
        return 1;
    else 
        return new Date(a.label) - new Date(b.label);
 });
```

Comment: `return (b.label === "No Value") - (a.label === "No Value") || new Date(a.label) - new Date(b.label);` (with the benefit of comparing multiple "No Value"s as equal) :-)